# Best Practice: Remove UUID or default_config_hash from Custom Content Type definitions?

Tags: 8

When I'm exporting the custom content type definitions using the UI, many of the resulting YML files hold a `uuid` and `default_config_hash`, like:

```
uuid: b69d8e54-076c-4a15-a396-19f49369fa68
...
_core:
  default_config_hash: 3aSvUp4PtrivflrkaLdNRL1USkZLsS7NdQroSiRX9mA
...
```

Now, when I'm using this as a basis for my custom module, is it recommended to remove those lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is best practice to remove both.

Drupal Console provides these options:

```
drupal config:export:single \
  --name=config.settings.name \
  --remove-uuid \
  --remove-config-hash
```

Or export an entire set of YAML files of a content type directly to the modules install folder:

```
drupal config:export:content:type page \
  --module="demo" \
  --optional-config \
  --remove-uuid \
  --remove-config-hash
```

See https://drupalconsole.com/docs/en/commands/config-export-content-type

Answer (score 7):

To manually remove all of the UUID and default_config_hash lines from your config files so that they don't conflict with those of a new site this can be done quite easily on the command line like so: (Linux)

```
find /path/to/PROFILE_NAME/config/install/ -type f -exec sed -i -e '/^uuid: /d' {} \;
find /path/to/PROFILE_NAME/config/install/ -type f -exec sed -i -e '/_core:/,+1d' {} \;
```

Here's the command for Mac OSX:

```
find /path/to/PROFILE_NAME/config/install/ -type f -exec sed -i '' '/^uuid: /d' {} \;
find /path/to/PROFILE_NAME/config/install/ -type f -exec sed -i '' '/_core:/{N;d;}' {} \;
```

See this https://www.drupal.org/docs/distributions/creating-distributions/how-to-write-a-drupal-installation-profile#config

Comment: We used to use these sed patterns in our profile but we discovered that JSON:API Extras can include the `_core` key in its config as a field name, and it was getting removed inadvertently.